# How to use more than one list item click that extends Activity implements onClicklistener

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using 3 listviews created in java code in my program. I use extends Activity that implements onitemclicklistener. Now, how to make different item click event for each listviwe separately?
Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain in detail? with code..?

Comment: sure. see my code in this link : http://pastebin.com/fGV10fh5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int index, long id)
{ 
    switch(view.getId())
    {
       case <listview1 Id> : //call method 1; break;

       case <listview2 Id> : //call method 2; break;

       case <listview3 Id> : //call method 3; break;

    }
}
```

This is a bad method.You should implement different classes for listeners.So you can modularize your code.

Comment: I create all listviews dynamically (i.e) without id. Then how to implement?

Comment: hey @PattabiRaman, you can use setTag(int key, Object tag) when creating the views and getTag(int key) when checking for the view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement OnItemClickListener in the Activity, instead use separate classes, for instance anonimous classes.

Or use a single listener, and detect the source of the event via the view parameter in the [callback method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29).

Answer (score 0):

if you see

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

It has parent AdapterView. so you can check on which adapter view it is clicked on.

I personally feel not to implement onItemClickListner for this type of instances.

use setOnItemClickListener(listener1) ... and so on for the 3 listViews. it's better.

You can write separate listeners for each of your listView.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new onItemClickLIstener for each of your ListView's.

You do so like this:

```
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int index, long id) {

        }
    });
```